# Moving RPG Character in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, timer

I am pretty new at C# and I wanted to make a simple *2D RPG* *(Role-Playing-Game)* character which can move around with its walking animation by simply using 'W' 'A' 'S' 'D' keywords. To do that, I used **Picture Box** to hold character image and **2 Timers** Tool, one for managing the '*walking*' animation by changing the picture every 100 ms, and the another timer is for moving that Picture Box location every 1 ms.

In the *'Form_KeyDown'* event, I set those 2 timers *Enabled = True* whenever user presses one of the moving keywords and I set those 2 timers *Enabled = False* in the *'Form_KeyUp'* event to indicate that the character is no longer moving.

Here is the first timer code that control the animation by changing the picture on each tick:

```
private void timerchangepic_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //movementPhase will determine the picture to be displayed, added by 1
    //every tick means character image change every tick
    movementPhase++;
    if (movementPhase > 4) movementPhase = 1;

    //determining which image is currently displayed
    if (charDirection == Direction.Front)
    {
        if (movementPhase == 1)
            pbcharacter.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("Icon\\front.png");
        else if (movementPhase == 2)
            pbcharacter.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("Icon\\front2.png");
        else if (movementPhase == 3)
            pbcharacter.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("Icon\\front3.png");
        else if (movementPhase == 4)
            pbcharacter.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("Icon\\front4.png");
    }

    //and goes the same for another 3 directions (left, right, and back)
}
```

Here is the second timer code that move the location of the character on each tick:

```
private void timermovement_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (charDirection == Direction.Front)
    {
        pbcharacter.Location = new Point(pbcharacter.Location.X, pbcharacter.Location.Y + 5);
    }

    //and goes the same for another 3 directions (left, right, and back)
}
```

**My problem is**: the character can't move well when I hold one of the moving keystroke. In a first second it works fine, but after a few second (2-3 seconds) pressing and holding 'S' stroke made the character stopped, moved a little, stopped again, moved a little and over and over. Besides, the animation only worked for 1 lap, the picture changed from '*front*' to '*front2*' until '*front4*' well, but not from '*front4*' back to '*front*'. In conclusion, the character's animation only ran for 1 shift, then it became a static image which moved a little, stopped, moved again, and stopped again whenever i hold 'S' button.

What is wrong with my codes? Are there any better approaches to implement a moving 2D character task with its animation?

Comment: You would be much better off using something like xna. [the code to do it within that](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/thewizard/theWizard.shtml) is much simpler since it handles the game loop for you. I would imagine the issue you are getting is due to threading issues of trying to update the ui between calls to setting the location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use somethimg more specific to build your application: XNA, MonoGame or Unity3D. But if you are using winforms I have several suggestion for you:
1) Cache images instead load them from file every time.
2) Cause Timer Events interval is not very accurate calculate ElapsedTime from last event. And make change +5 to something dependent of ElapsedTime.
3) Instead using several timers organize game loop to handle your events.
4) Use Double Buffer on your form.

Comment: Thankyou! all of you guys did answer my problem. I will claim this as the answering one for explaining in most detail :)

Answer (score 0):

Building a game using windows forms can be incredible hard, and also extremely inefficient. If you were to use XNA, which isn't that difficult to learn, you could create a much better and much stronger game.

If your using WinForms i will presume your a beginner so I wouldn't bother with unity or mono as they are much more complicated. If you still reject this I would advise you to:

1. Cache images
2. more accurately calculate ElapsedTime and use dependencies
3. use a while loop to repeat for each tick, this point should fix your problem

Hope to have been of help.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you must make your game using windows form then you need to 
at least handle your update with a gameloop instead of form timers and
if your moving things around your going to need some kind of clock to 
help your game run at the same speed on any cpu